# how can I create a regex that can picks words that don't start with '#' or '.'

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a JavaScript function that can look through a string of CSS selectors and select the the elements that are tag names ( body , p , h1 ) from the other selectors such as as IDs and classes ( #test .test1)

An example would be the string:
"span#a53195yio1rnin6d2t9 div.first"

would only return span and div leaving the rest

This is what i have so far but it selects everything after ' # ' or ' .'

## (\b(?!#|!.)\w+)\b

Comment: What happens with `property` and `values` inside the CSS selectors? Are there any at all? Have they been stripped away before using the regular expression? If they are there, should them be matched or skipped?

Comment: No they aren't stripped away, I just have a bunch of css selector test cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your environment supports lookbehind, just lookbehind for a space or the beginning of the line:

```js
const str = "span#a53195yio1rnin6d2t9 div.first";
console.log(
  str.match(/(?:^|(?<= ))\w+/gm)
);
```

Otherwise, if you have to support older browsers, you'll have to iterate through the matches manually - *match* the beginning of the string or the space, then *capture* the next word characters in a group, and extract that capturing group:

```js
const str = "span#a53195yio1rnin6d2t9 div.first";
const re = /(?:^| )(\w+)/gm;
const matches = [];
let match;
while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  matches.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Not just "old browsers" Firefox 66 here and It is not supported. I believe lookbehind assertions are not valid (at least until ES2018)